# Regex pattern captures address well but fails to detect the zipcode and returns only the first letter of the city

Tags: python-3.x, regex

In this case the pattern captures the address well but fails when it comes to the zip code and the city:

The text fragment is:

```
'''
 Kοινοποίηση:  • Εταιρεία: «ICON FITNESS ΕΚΜΕΤΑΛΛΕΥΣΗ ΓΥΜΝΑΣΤΗΡΙΩΝ ΑΝΩΝΥΜΗ ΕΤΑΙΡΕΙΑ» Δ/νση: ΣΕΚΕΡΗ 5 Τ.Κ.: 10671, ΑΘΗΝΑ • Περιφέρεια Αττικής  Γεν. Δ/νση Ανάπτυξης Δ/νση Ανάπτυξης Π.Ε. Κεντρικού Τομέα Αθηνών Τμήμα Ανωνύμω
'''
```

The regex pattern is:

```
dieythinsi_pattern1 = re.compile(r'Kοινοποίηση:?.*«[^«»]*»\s+.+?:?(\w+)\s(\d+)\s*(?:,?\s*(\d{5}))?(?:,?\s*([\w]+))?', re.I)
```

This returns the street and the number but fails to detect the zipcoe and returns only the initial letter of the city.

The address is the following:  `ΣΕΚΕΡΗ 5 Τ.Κ.: 10671, ΑΘΗΝΑ` where `10671` is the zip code.

Comment: Try https://regex101.com/r/PFXWED/1, `Kοινοποίηση:?.*«[^«»]*».*?(\w+)\s+(\d+)\s*(?:,?\s*(\d{5}))?(?:,?\s*([\w\s.]+))?`, but the problem is to identify the city pattern.